# pdfView not showing pdf

Tags: android, pdf

I am using barteksc pdfViewer library to show a string in pdf view.
I have the code below:

```
PDFView pdfView  = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
String text = "some string";
Uri textUri = Uri.parse(text);
pdfView.fromUri(textUri).load();
```

My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PdfActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but the pdfView remains empty. Have anyone any idea why i cant preview the pdfView?

Answer (score 0):

> to show a string in pdf view

You can't do that. PDFViewer is able to display PDF only.

The different methods to set a PDF into the PDFViewer are the following:

```
pdfView.fromUri(Uri)
pdfView.fromFile(File)
pdfView.fromBytes(byte[])
pdfView.fromStream(InputStream)
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
```

If you have a `String`, try to convert it into a `ByteArray`

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: Ok i convert string to PdfDocument. But then how do i set the PdfDocument to viewer?